# Use email address in contact lookup search

Tags: lookup

My opportunities are linked one to one with contacts. Is there a way when I am doing a contact lookup to just use the contact's email address instead of their name? This is a much more personally identifiable string than the name, especially if we have 6 John Smiths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. You can find it here. Summary below. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_enhanced_lookup_enable.htm&language=en_US

Go to Setup->Customize->Search->Search Settings

Here you can select which objects you would like to search every field. This also allows wildcard * searching I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can add the contact.email field to the "Search Layouts" for the Contact sObject.

Go to Setup->Customize->Contacts->Search Layouts
Click "Edit" on the Lookup Dialogs row, and add the email field. What the heck, just add the email field on all the Search Layouts!

What your users will see now is both the Contact Name and the Email... both searchable.

Comment: Hi John, It looks like that only changes the columns that show up in the search, not that it makes the email searchable. "Note that your choices only determine the display of search results and do not affect the fields that are actually searched. "

But that did lead me down a rabbit hole to the following link. It looks like it might be an option with enhanced lookup, but not standard lookup, whatever that means.
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_fields_contact.htm&language=en_US